# Getting stuck retrieving a dom element

Tags: javascript

I am trying to tidy up some code - and have got stuck. Everything was going fine 'console logging' simple statements between the various functions. However; now plumbing in DOM elements; I cannot seem to get hold of them. Any advice would be very much appreciated.

**Original Attempt**

```js
let header = {
    nav_btn: document.getElementById('navigation_link'),
    sayBye: function() {
        console.log('bye');
        console.log(nav_btn.innerHTML);
    },
    sayHi: function() {
        header.sayBye();
    }
};

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
 document.getElementById('search_form_btn_m').addEventListener('click', header.sayHi)
});
```

```html
 <a href="" id='navigation_link' class='navigation_link'>&#9776;</a>
```

**Second Attempt**
Hmmm... this is still not working :\ Some helpful people presented some demos. So I stripped the code back to basics; in the hope of establishing what the error is.

**Third Attempt(s)**
Works - not what I wanted.

```
let header = {
    sayBye: function() {
        console.log(document.getElementById('navigation_link').innerHTML);
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    header.sayBye();
}
```

This does not

```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null at Object.sayBye

let header = {
    nav_btn: document.getElementById('navigation_link'),
    sayBye: function() {
        console.log(header.nav_btn.innerHTML);
    }
}
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    header.sayBye();
}
```

**This works** - seems rather bloated? Why does it only work wrapping my navigation_link in a function? Otherwise, it generates a cannot read property error (as per the above).

```
let header = {
    nav_btn: function() {
        let btn = document.getElementById('navigation_link').innerHTML;
        return btn;
    },
    sayBye: function() {
        console.log(header.nav_btn());
    },
    sayHi: function() {
        header.sayBye()
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.getElementById('search_form_btn_m').addEventListener('click', header.sayHi);
}
```

**Fourth Attempt**
The suggested reason for the error is because header.nav_btn is trying to access navigation_link as its being defined. 
I modified my code - on pure instincts hoping it would work.

It works in 'run code snippet'. It does not when it is on my page with lots of other stuff. err 'Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null'

Any guidance on how to get this to work would be great. I feel like I am on the verge of making a breakthrough in my knowledge.

```js
let header = {
    nav_btn: document.getElementById('navigation_link').innerHTML,
    init: function() {
        header.nav_btn;
        header.sayBye()        
    },
    sayBye: function() {
        console.log(header.nav_btn);
    },
}
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
document.getElementById('search_form_btn_m').addEventListener('click', header.init);
});
```

```html
                <a href="" id='navigation_link' class='navigation_link'>&#9776;</a>
                <button id='search_form_btn_m' class='search_form_open_m'>Hit Me</button>
```

Comment: Put more code, you forgot the "search_form_btn_m" element.

Comment: Change `nav_btn` to `header.nav_btn`. It is not a variable, but a property.

Comment: You correctly wait for `load` before retrieving `#search_form_btn_m`, but you're trying to load `navigation_link` as soon as you define `let header`, which may well be before that element exists.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol thank you for your message. Can I get my head around this? So when I type `'load', header.sayHi`. Does it take a scalpel to my object literal and only onload's .sayHi? The rest of the functions in header are processed line by line as the browser see's them?

Comment: ... No? The object is created when you define it.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

Look at the line "`console.log(header.nav_btn.innerHTML);`": you have to put where the code should look for "`nav_btn`". Here it's a property of "`header`", so you put "`header.nav_btn`".

```js
let header = {
    nav_btn: document.getElementById('navigation_link'),
    sayBye: function() {
        console.log('bye');
        console.log(header.nav_btn.innerHTML);
    },
    sayHi: function() {
        header.sayBye();
    }
};

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
 document.getElementById('search_form_btn_m').addEventListener('click', header.sayHi)
});
```

```html
 <a href="" id='navigation_link' class='navigation_link'>&#9776;</a>
 <input type="button" id="search_form_btn_m" />
```

Comment: You should explain something. "Does this work for you?" is not a good answer.

Comment: I edited my answer. I though it was pretty obvious.

Comment: thank you. May I ask if you have any words of wisdom? this still does not work?